# EXTJS 6.0.1 [W] For WAI-ARIA compliance, IMG elements SHOULD have an alt attribute

Tags: extjs

I updated my application from 5.1.2 to EXTJS 6.0.1 and this causes this warning and all the icons from actioncolumn disappeared

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is generated from field image.

set property "alt" to solve.

for actioncolumn use

```
 xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                        width: 25,
                        items: [
                            {
                                icon: '../xxxxxxx/xxxxx.png'
                            }
```